# Display specific columns in Sql Tables

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, schema, database-schema

How can I display only the specfic columns from `INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS` schema?

Ex:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rate_Structure'
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Returns:

```
+-------------+
|             |
| COLUMN_NAME |
+-------------+
|    a        |
|    b        |
|    c        |
|    d        |
|    e        |
+-------------+
```

How to show only a and e columns?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select specific rows and columns from an SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682736/select-specific-rows-and-columns-from-an-sql-database)

Comment: You should learn how SQL works. This is a query like any other, so you filter the results the same way you filter results for any other query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how to Show only a and e columns

Simply, by filtering the results in **[`WHERE`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/where-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)** clause as

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME    
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rate_Structure' and COLUMN_NAME in ('a','e') 
-- You can also use: and (COLUMN_NAME = 'a' or COLUMN_NAME = 'e')    
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

You need to add the condition to get what you need, `and COLUMN_NAME in ('a','e')` will return only `COLUMN_NAME` has `'a'` or `'e'` value.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add aditional conditions like:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME 
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS 
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rate_Structure'  
  AND data_type = 'int'    -- condition to get only specific columns
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION;
```

Comment: The OP want `a` and `e` columns no matter the data type

Answer (score 1):

Add another condition in where

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME    
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS    
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'rate_Structure' and COLUMN_NAME in ('a','c')    
ORDER BY ORDINAL_POSITION
```

Comment: It's `e` column instead of `c`

Answer (score 0):

You can use INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS as below

```
USE Test
GO
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'SalesTerritory'
AND COLUMN_NAME = 'Region'
```