# How to loop through each item in database

Tags: php, sql, database, loops

I have a PHP script I'm writing where I have to get data from a database and convert the results into a static HTML page. I'm trying to loop through all the items 1 by 1 in a particular database and grab the value that's in their "nid" column as I go along. I started the script. I have the database connection. Just stuck on how I should do the loop. Should it be a while loop or a for loop? If so how do I go about looping through the items in the table 1 by 1 and grabbing a particular column value? Also attached is the screenshot of the database so you can see the column I'm trying to target. [image]

```
<?php
    // Establish all database credential variables
    $serverName = "localhost";
    $username = "admin";
    $password = "peaches";
    $databaseName = "static_site";

    // Create Database Connection
    $connection = new mysqli($serverName, $username, $password, $databaseName);

    // Check Database Connection
    if ($connection->connect_error) {
      die("Connection failed:" . $connection->connect_error);
    } // line ends if statement

    $queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid FROM node_revision";
    // line above creates variable $queryNodeRevision > selects column "nid" from table "node_revision"

    $dataBaseQueryResults = mysqli_query($connection, $queryNodeRevision);
    // line above creates variable $dataBaseQueryResults > actually queries the database and passes in 2 variables
    // passes in database connection variable and variable that selects "nid" column from "node_revision" table
    ?>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Select specific rows and columns from an SQL database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36682736/select-specific-rows-and-columns-from-an-sql-database)

Answer (score 0):

Use `while loop` and [mysqli_fetch_array](https://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to fetch the value of `nid` for each row.

```
$queryNodeRevision = "SELECT nid FROM node_revision";

$results=mysqli_query($queryNodeRevision);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

    echo $row['nid'];
}
```

Comment: Thank you but I don't want to display the rows. I want to loop through each row 1 by 1 and grab the value of column "nid" for each row.

Comment: with this you will get `nid` value for each row, try it and let me know

Comment: Never use mysql_* functions. They are deprecated!

Comment: @AmineKOUIS So you're saying the data from the "nid" column should be displayed on my page if all goes well?

Comment: Yeah that's it!

Comment: But I don't need the results to display. I just need to grab the value of what's in column "nid" for each row. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: the value of `nid` is here `$row['nid'];` if you don't want to display it on your page, just delete `echo` and do whatever you want by `$row['nid'];`

Comment: I just checked it and this code is actually getting the values of all the columns not just "nid' column

Comment: It's a bit strange, check your query, you have made `SELECT nid` not `SELECT *` so with `$row['nid'];` you will get only *nid* column value.